# Does Cognito user authentication provide complete security for an asp.net web api running on EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have an ASP.NET web api running on a Windows EC2 instance together with DynamoDB data layer. I've been looking for alternative choices on aws to secure my web api.

For that purpose, I read AWS STS and API Gateway docs. API Gateway is the first choice but I wouldn't like to use it because it forces me to learn node.js.

Cognito seems the best choice for me because it will also handle both mobil and web users. I know that Cognito also provide security on aws resources.

My question is:
Is it possible to secure Web APIs running on EC2 instances without using security tokens. Can cognito control all incoming API calls without need any additional security steps?

Thanks